# Error:(7) Error parsing XML: junk after document element

Tags: android, xml

So basically it's this ol' chestnut... I've seen this question is asked rather a lot but couldn't relate their solution to mine, so perhaps you'd be able to help me in addition.

Here's my activity_splash.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/primary_dark"
    android:id="@+id/imgLogo"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgLogo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/splash"
        android:contentDescription=""
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/AppVersion"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imgLogo"/>

    <com.app.tvng.blogpress.views.VerticalTextView
        android:id="@+id/companyname"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dip"
        android:padding="4dip"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:text="@string/copyright"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

thank you for your help

Comment: is it pointing to any line? can you post the complete error log

Comment: @cooervo the complete error log :

Error:(7) Error parsing XML: junk after document element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try including tools namespace: `xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"` 
and using `tools:background="@color/primary_dark"` instead of `android:background="@color/primary_dark"`

Like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                tools:background="@color/primary_dark"
                android:id="@+id/imgLogo">
```